# Start-Process : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters (run as admin another .ps1)

Tags: windows, powershell

Good morning guys,

I am quite new with programming in PowerShell..

I have a problem since this morning and I don't understand why.. I am working on a script for my company, and it works perfectly. But the problem is executing it. The script ist named Script.ps1 and I run it through another one who run another PS window with admin proviledges.

```
$path = 'Script.ps1'
Start-Process powershell.exe -verb RunAs -ArgumentList "-file $path"
```

Since Friday was working perfectly, but this morning this command gives the following error.

`Start-Process : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
At line:1 char:1
+ Start-Process powershell.exe -verb RunAs -ArgumentList "-file $path" -NoNewWindo ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Start-Process], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand`

(In the error is written also a -NoNewWindow, I used it for understanding which error came out, or the new process disappears in a second)

I tried all.. Do someone can understand what's wrong?

Thanks all!

Comment: You code and your error message show a different command line!  The parameter `-NoNewWindow` does not work with `-Verb` !!! Please read the error message and then read the help

Comment: That is right, my mistake. The problem is that, when I leave the normale command the "new process" who is started closes in half second and I can't understand there what is the problem, I can just see a millisecond of something written in red

Comment: So you should add error handling to your script. [Get-Help about_try_catch_finally](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_try_catch_finally?view=powershell-7)

Comment: Ok finally I could made it, I changed the syntax of the string, not appears like that and seems working..

powershell.exe "Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList '-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NonInteractive -NoProfile -File $path' -Verb RunAs"

There was also something wrong with the exec policy.

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Please consider posting your solution as an answer and marking that as solved.